# pandas: create a column of comma separated value based on the len of strings in another cloumn

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a dataframe like the following:

```
df = {"text":["see you in five minutes", "she is my friend", "she goes to school in five minutes","he is my friend"]}
```

and I would like to create another column of comma separated repeated value based on the length of the strings in each row of the df column.

the desired output:

```
df = {"text":["see you in five minutes", "she is my friend", "she goes to school in five minutes","he is my friend"],
      "new_text":["s,s,s,s,s", "s,s,s,s", "s,s,s,s,s,s,s","s,s,s,s"]}
```

I tried `df.text.str.split().apply(len)` but I am not sure how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this,

```
df['new_text'] = (
    df.text.str.split().str.len()
        .apply(lambda x: x * ['s']).str.join(',')
)
```

---

```
                                 text       new_text
0             see you in five minutes      s,s,s,s,s
1                    she is my friend        s,s,s,s
2  she goes to school in five minutes  s,s,s,s,s,s,s
3                     he is my friend        s,s,s,s
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) along with [`Series.str.len`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html) to get the length of strings then use a simple list comprehension with `join`:

```
df['new_text'] = [','.join(['s']*n) for n in df['text'].str.split().str.len()]
```

Result:

```
                                 text       new_text
0             see you in five minutes      s,s,s,s,s
1                    she is my friend        s,s,s,s
2  she goes to school in five minutes  s,s,s,s,s,s,s
3                     he is my friend        s,s,s,s
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    import pandas as pd

    def calc_size (row):
       size = len(row['text'].split())
       out=""
       print(size)
       for i in range(size):
           
           if i<size:
               out+="s,"
           else:
               out+="s"
               return out


    data = {"text":["see you in five minutes", "she is my friend", "she goes to school in five minutes","he is my friend"]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df["new_column"] = df.apply(lambda row: calc_size(row), axis=1)
    print(df)
```

```
text     new_column
0             see you in five minutes      s,s,s,s,s
1                    she is my friend        s,s,s,s
2  she goes to school in five minutes  s,s,s,s,s,s,s
3                     he is my friend        s,s,s,s
```